# What's the IP or URL firebase-admin hits for sending messages through FCM?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have issue when try to send FCM notification.
I think this due to the server limit access to outside.
What I need to know is what is the URL or IP that firebase-admin hit for auth or send fcm?
Because the IP in error message seems like always changed.

```
Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.217.194.84:443. Error code: EHOSTUNREACH\"."}
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.217.194.84:443. Error code: EHOSTUNREACH".
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/administrator/node/FCMService/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/administrator/node/FCMService/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/home/administrator/node/FCMService/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at /home/administrator/node/FCMService/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:121:23
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:18224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Your code is failing well before it attempts to make a connection to FCM. It's failing to obtain an OAuth2 token. I believe that's from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token.

Answer (score 0):

The host name for sending messages starts with `fcm.googleapis.com`, and is typically accessed over HTTPS. For cases like this it really helps to realize that the Firebase Admin SDKs are open-source, and the relevant code for the Node.js SDK is [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/messaging/messaging.ts#L36).